# No setting to set default home app on Doogee Y9 Plus

Tags: launcher, default-applications, android-9, doogee

I have an old Android 9 (it's a Doogee Y9 Plus) device on which I would like to set Nova Launcher as the default home app, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set it through the device's settings.

Every guide I could find states that you can change your default home app under Settings > Apps & notifications > Default apps > Home app, yet "Home app" isn't an option in Default apps on this device.

When I navigate to either the device's default home app (which is called "Aurora Launcher") or Nova Launcher in the settings, "Home app" is there and is set to "Yes" and "No" respectively, but when I click on the option there, it takes me back to "Default apps" where the option doesn't exist.

My question is: Is there a way to bypass this and forcefully change the launcher? Btw, if possible, I'd like to force uninstall or at least disable the native launcher after the change. I've been finding things about ADB, but since I've never used ADB before, I want to know if there are some other ways and if not, how to use ADB to fix it.

Comment: What happens when you open Nova settings, then click on "Select default launcher"?

Comment: I've tried that too. It takes me to the "Default apps" section in my settings, and as previously mentioned, "Home app" doesn't exist as an option that I can change there.